# source.attr('id') is undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I got this code from someone, and it should be working, but it is coming up undefined for `source.attr('id')`, and I can't figure out why.

```
var vendorTypeSelect = $("#select-vendor-type");
var vendorLocationSelect = $("#select-vendor-location");
createDropDown(vendorTypeSelect);
createDropDown(vendorLocationSelect);

function createDropDown(source){
    console.log(source);
    var customClass = source.attr('id');  <--- undefined????
    console.log(customClass);

    customClass = customClass.substr(customClass.indexOf("#") + 1)
```

Console log of source pulls up the object including it's id, but console log for customClass says 'undefined'. It also says undefined when I put `$("#select-vendor-location").attr('id');`

I have the page uploaded here:
http://pixeldesigns.ca/files/blush/

Comment: is the code executed on dom ready? it looks like there are no elements with id `select-vendor-location`

Comment: Your code is executed in head, after parsing it, not on DOM ready, so a node with that ID does not yet exist.

Comment: wrap the code into `jQuery(document).ready(function () { /**/ });` or `$(function () { /**/ });`

Comment: BTW, if you ever find yourself using `.attr('id')` off a jquery object--don't. Just use `.id` (and if you're using a newer jQuery, `.prop` is a better alternative for things like `id`,`href`,`src`, etc.)

Comment: AHHH! I knew it was going to be something I should've thought of and make me feel stupid. :( Thanks all, and thanks for the additional tips Brad.

Comment: @BradChristie I thought prop was used more for setting properties like the checked property of a checkbox, where as attr was for reading attributes like name?

Comment: id, href, src are all properties of the DOM node. Save the overhead of spinning up a jQuery object just to access id. e.g. use `el.id` over `$(el).prop('id')`. Using `$(el)` creates a new jQuery object which is excessive for such a simple accessor.

Comment: @andrew attr is for hard-coded attribute values, whereas prop is for properties only living live (for javascript, for example if you attach an object as property of the node, it isn't persisted into an attribute of the actual DOM node)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is, when

```
$(".dropdown dd ul li a").click(function() {
```

these elements don't exist yet. (They even exist not until you built them in your createDropDown function.) You need to wrap your entire script into

```
jQuery(document).ready(function ($) {  // or $(function () {
    var vendorTypeSelect = $("#select-vendor-type");
    var vendorLocationSelect = $("#select-vendor-location");
    createDropDown(vendorTypeSelect);
    createDropDown(vendorLocationSelect);

    //...
});
```

because inside of the ready event, that is fired after all HTML has been parsed, these elements do exist now. You can even define your `createDropDown` function outside of (preferably before) `$(document).ready` but you have to call it inside, because it works on the assumption that the element already exists.